# Add referrer URL to end of new URL

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. I store the URL, then direct to a new URL, and I want the current URL to be at the end of it (following "?url="). However, the code just produces infinite redirects.

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;

for(var i = 0; i < targetURLs.length; i++)
  if(currentURL.toString().indexOf(targetURLs[i]) >= 0) {
    window.stop();  
    window.location.href = 'https://example.com?url=' + 
      currentURL.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Where does `targetURLs` get populated?

Comment: I just posted the relevant snippet of code. `targetURLs` is populated directly above that segment (and I know that part works because the script reaches the code inside of the `if` statement).

Comment: Okay, but if the page the code redirects to is hitting this code again, then what is guaranteeing that it won't have the same result as the first time (Is the url being added to `targetURLs`.)?

Comment: Ah, that was exactly it! Since the current URL was contained in the new URL, then the new URL was also in `targetURLs`. I now modified the `if` statement so it checks that `currentURL.toString().indexOf('https://example.com') == 0`. Testing now...

Comment: `indexOf` will return `-1` if what searching for isn't found. So you would want to do `currentURL.toString().indexOf('https://example.com') == -1` to see if current url isn't `https://example.com`.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies, I meant < 0.